# Stored Procedure / Stored Function: SELECT in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, composite-types

I have created a stored procedure / function with a simple SELECT in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_proc2()
RETURNS SETOF procedure AS
$DELIMETER$
SELECT * FROM procedure;
$DELIMETER$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
```

This one works but when I tried to be specific like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_proc2(INT)
RETURNS SETOF procedure AS
$DELIMETER$
SELECT "Fname" FROM procedure where "Id" = $1;
$DELIMETER$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
```

it returns an error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return procedure
DETAIL:  Final statement returns character instead of integer at
column 1. CONTEXT:  SQL function "select_proc2"
```

I tried any solution that I can think of. Anyone here know how to solve this error?

Comment: From your table definition we would be able to see whether you actually named the column with double-quoted CamelCase ("Id", "Fname") or you need to remove the double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt the `RETURN` type to what's actually returned:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_proc2(int)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
SELECT "Fname" FROM procedure WHERE "Id" = $1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql
```

In your second version you only return one column. From the name I am deriving the data type `text`, but that's just a guess.

If `"Id"` is the primary key column of `procedure` or otherwise defined `UNIQUE`, only one row can be returned and you can simplify to:

```
  RETURNS text
```

Also don't quote the language name. `sql` is an identifier here, not a string literal. It's only tolerated for historic reason, but it's probably going to be an error in future versions.

Concerning your column names: My advise is to use non-quoted lower-case identifiers exclusively in Postgres. Start by reading the chapter ["Identifiers and Key Words"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) to learn about the significance of `"id"`, `"Id"`, `ID` or `id` as column name.

Answer (score 0):

remove quotes around field names (without "):

```
  CREATE FUNCTION select_proc2(INT)
  RETURNS SETOF procedure AS
  $DELIMETER$
  SELECT Fname FROM procedure where Id = $1;
  $DELIMETER$
  LANGUAGE 'sql'
```

Comment: I tried but it show an error

ERROR:  column "fname" does not exist
LINE 4: SELECT Fname FROM procedure where Id = $1;

Comment: well, then you have to provide the table description

Comment: table description?..can you give me an example of it?

Comment: The advise may or may not help, the actual (obvious) error is not pointed out.

Comment: Don't quote the language name, it should be `sql`, not `'sql'`.